# Finding Min-Max

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Issue** Not able to get Min-Max of parts using formulas, shows wrong value

**What I did**

Here is my formula

```
=MAX(VLOOKUP(A2,TAT!A:C,3,FALSE))& "/" &MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,TAT!A:C,3,FALSE))
```

[Here is sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeyY3.png)

[Here is sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KrZo.png)

**Results that I want?**
Basically, I just want the Min-Max from TAT sheet to be shown in BER Summary Sheet in the Min-Max TAT column.
[What I want it to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7dqS.png)

Is something wrong with the formula or am I not using the right approach to the formula at all?

Comment: VLOOKUP returns the first match only and not all of them so the min and max will be the same number always.  What version do you have?

Comment: I have office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 365:

```
=MAXIFS(TAT!C:C,TAT!A:A,A2)& "/" &MINIFS(TAT!C:C,TAT!A:A,A2)
```

Comment: DUDE! It worked. Thanks a lot. But could you tell why did we use MAXIFS and not just MAX? Thanks

Comment: Because max will return the max of everything, while Maxifs will filter the data based on the criteria and only return the max of the filtered data.  If this worked, please consider marking it as correct by clicking the check box by the answer.